# Best type of flu shot

Tags: vaccination, influenza

This October I am going to new Doctor who is close to my home. Old Doctor passed away.

I went to CDC website and it lists many type of flu shots

http://www.cdc.gov/flu/protect/vaccine/vaccines.htm

In general:

What type of vaccine would be good for healthy lady in mid-30s?

What type of vaccine would be good for elderly who are somewhat active, doing stuff around the house, but suffer the regular aches and pains, who are early 70s?

Comment: Why the downvote? Because I said the Doctor is pushy?

Comment: Not my downvote, but there are a few things that make this question difficult to answer - firstly it contains several different questions. Are you interested in types of flu vaccines or advice on communicating with your doctor? Secondly, there is much more to determining a suitable vaccine for someone than age. E.g. vaccines produced on chicken embryos are not suitable for people allergic to eggs (nothing to do with age) etc. Many contraindications and precautions are listed at the website you linked. If you could make your question more specific, it still might be salvaged.

Comment: Oh, and by specific I don't mean asking for personalised health advice, that's strictly off topic - we cannot recommend a specific vaccine for you nor your parents or anyone else over the internet. The best we can do is answer specific questions or clarify something you don't understand from the material you went through in you research :-).

Comment: @Lucky I edited question, see now

Comment: I think that it's much better now and has better chance of getting an answer. I think that you will probably get a better answer from physicians on this website (this is not exactly my area), but if there isn't one for a while, I'll see what I can dig up :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2015 Advisory Committee on Immunization Practices (ACIP) does not express a preference for use of any particular product over another for persons for whom more than one type of vaccine is appropriate and available.

The major recommendations concern age, state of health, allergies (some vaccines are specifically recommended for people allergic to eggs or to previous vaccines, pregnancy, etc.), fear of needles (there are multiple ways now to receive influenza vaccines including microneedle intradermal doses, intramuscular jet, and nasal, along with the routine IM injection), timing of the vaccine (especially in the elderly and young).

*A previous severe allergic reaction to influenza vaccine, regardless of the component suspected of being responsible for the reaction, is a contraindication to future receipt of the vaccine.*

Basically, if the vaccine (in the US) is FDA approved, it should be fine.

> What type of vaccine would be good for healthy lady in mid-30s[?]

Assuming that you're **not pregnant**, in the absence of data (recent studies including the 2014 flu season) demonstrating consistent greater relative effectiveness of the current quadrivalent formulation of Live Attenuated Influenza Vaccine (LAIV), preference for LAIV over Inactivated Influenza Vaccine (IIV) is no longer recommended.

In your age range and state of health, you should *avoid* the LAIV if

> - you've experienced severe allergic reactions to the vaccine or any of its components, or to a previous dose of any influenza vaccine
> - you have a history of egg allergy
> - you've taken influenza antiviral medications within the previous 48 hours
> - you care for severely immunosuppressed persons who require a protective environment

If you live with someone with bad asthma, you might want to consult your doctor about which vaccine is better for you.

> What type of vaccine would be good for elderly who are somewhat active, doing stuff around the house, but suffer the regular aches and pains, who are early 70s?

Well, they should avoid the LAIV. In addition, they should consult their doctor if they have any medical conditions, and for information about the timing of the vaccine (the optimal timing for those over 65 varies from continent to continent and even country to country.)

Given all the above, I have only ever been asked, "Are you allergic to eggs?" before getting a flu shot!

<sub>[Prevention and Control of Influenza with Vaccines: Recommendations of the Advisory Committee on Immunization Practices, United States, 2015–16 Influenza Season](http://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/preview/mmwrhtml/mm6430a3.htm)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for last year's link. It helped a lost. This year when I try to find one for 2016-17, I get 50 page document http://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/volumes/65/rr/rr6505a1.htm. Please give link for abridged document, i.e. 6 to 8 pages